# target selected list item in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I'm using foundation drop-down

You can have a look at it here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html#

I've created a dropdown with the following code

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" >Date Range  </a>
    <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown large date-menu" drop-down-content>
        <li id="custom">Custom</li>
        <li id="today">Today</li>
        <li id="yesterday">Yesterday</li>
        <li id="sundaytoToday">This Week(Sun-Today)</li>
        <li id="montoToday">This Week(Mon-Today)</li>
     </ul>
```

I want to get the value/id of the selected element

I've tried like below, but it's not working

```
'click #drop1 li':"changeDateRange",

changeDateRange : function(event)
    {
        var ss=$(this).attr('id');
        console.log(ss);
        if(ss=="custom")
        {
            console.log("custom if");
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
...
var ss = event.currentTarget.id
...
```

Answer (score 1):

So in backbone, the "this" for the delegate events are bound to the class itself.  So you would have to use "event.currentTarget"

```
    'click #drop1 li':"changeDateRange",

changeDateRange : function(event)
    {
        var ss=$(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
        console.log(ss);
        if(ss=="custom")
        {
            console.log("custom if");
        }
    },
```